# Isset inline conditions does not work

Tags: php, conditional-statements, isset

I am using inline condition to get some value, but I do not understand why it does not return the good value.
I want to get `false` value but it is return `test`. What I am doing wrong? I have searched in questions but I didn't find why my script does not work. Thanks.

This is the script,

```
$val1 = null;
$val2 = false;
$val3 = 0;
$val4 = "test";

$newValue = isset($val1) ? $val1 : isset($val2) ? $val2 : isset($val3) ? $val3 : isset($val4) ? $val4 : -1;
var_dump($newValue); // print test
```

Comment: Instead of `isset()`, I would suggest use `empty()`.

Comment: isset() test if null or "undefined", but not the false or 0 ? Isn't it ?

Comment: @JigarShah I want to get false, not "test"

Comment: got that I just misread the post

Comment: @JigarShah Sorry for my bad english. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to surround your tests using braces `()` :

```
$newValue = isset($val1) ? $val1 : (
                isset($val2) ? $val2 : (
                    isset($val3) ? $val3 : (
                        isset($val4) ? $val4 :
                            -1
                    )
                )
            ) ;

var_dump($newValue) ; // Outputs : bool(false)
```

As of PHP 7.0, you could use the [null coalescing operator](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php) using the `??` characters :

```
$newValue = $val1 ?? $val2 ?? $val3 ?? $val4 ?? -1 ;
var_dump($newValue) ; // Outputs : bool(false)
```

Comment: o/p should be `string(4) "test"`

Answer (score 0):

Though not a complex code just want to add:

While using the ternary operator, avoid nesting or stacking your operations, even if you’re comfortable using them, as this can lead to very confusing code and unintuitive results. It’s still best to use if statements for complex situations.(www.sitepoint.com)

```
if (isset($val1)) {
    $newValue = $val1;
}elseif (isset($val2)) {
    $newValue = $val2;
}elseif (isset($val3)) {
    $newValue = $val3;
}elseif (isset($val4)) {
    $newValue = $val4;
}
var_dump($newValue);
```